# How can I feed photos from a Flickr RSS feed into Pinterest?

Tags: perl, rss, flickr

Pinterest seems not to have much of an API at the moment, but I'd like to feed my Flickr photostream to Pinterest anyway.

I presume that I could use LWP::UserAgent in Perl to navigate their usual web UI if I had to, but I'm hoping someone else already has a tool for this. (If only ifttt had a Pinterest channel!)

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: if you know (or want to learn!) PHP theres an unofficial API here: https://github.com/kellan/pinterest.api.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to be due to copyrighted images I think. Yoiu can try this service, not sure how or if it works  though

http://repin.me/